# Porque no funciona correctamente la opcion borrar archivo?

Tags: java, archivo, clase, menu

La opcion 4 de eliminar el archivo no funciona si ya he utilizado la opcion 3 de ver el archivo, por ejemplo ejecuto el programa uso la opcion 1,2 y 3 sin problema todo funciona bien pero al querer borrar el archivo con opcion 4 no se puede eliminar el archivo, en cambio si utilizo la opcion 1 y 2 y luego la 4 el archivo se elimina sin problemas, solo no se elimina cuando uso la opcion 3 sinceramente no se me ocurre a que se debe este problema por eso si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho

public class Practica {

```
public static String nombrefichero;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero1;
    do{
    System.out.println("1-Crear archivo");
    System.out.println("2-Enviar dato");
    System.out.println("3-Ver archivo");
    System.out.println("4-Eliminar archivo");
    System.out.println("5-Salir del progama");
    
     
    System.out.println("Ingresa la opcion que deseas");
    numero1 = scan.nextInt();
    switch(numero1){
        case 1:
            Scanner scan6 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del archivo");
            nombrefichero = scan6.nextLine();
            System.out.println(nombrefichero);
            File fichero = new File (nombrefichero);
    try {

    if (fichero.createNewFile())
    System.out.println("El fichero se ha creado correctamente");
    else
    System.out.println("No ha podido ser creado el fichero");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
}
    String dato2;
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresa el primer dato para el archivo");
    dato2 = scan2.nextLine();
    
    
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fichero.getAbsoluteFile(), true));
    bw.write(dato2);
    bw.close();
    
            
            break;
        case 2:
            
            String dato6;
            Scanner scan7 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingresa el dato que deseas enviarle al archivo");
            dato6 = scan7.nextLine();
            
            File fichero2 = new File (nombrefichero);
            
            BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fichero2.getAbsoluteFile(), true));
            bw2.write(dato6);
            bw2.close();
            break;
        case 3:
            try {
            File fichero3 = new File (nombrefichero);
            BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero3));
            String strng;
            while ((strng = obj.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(strng);
              } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
            break;
               
        case 4:
            File fichero4 = new File (nombrefichero);
            if(fichero4.delete()){
                System.out.println("El archivo se ha eliminado");
                
            }else{
                System.out.println("No se pudo eliminar el fichero");
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Se ha cerrado el programa exitosamente");
            break;
            default:
            break;
    }
    }while(numero1>=1 && numero1<=4);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace años no programo en Java. Sin embargo, mirando tu código, en la opción 3 no usas el método `close()` del objeto de la clase `BufferedReader`. En las opciones 1 y 2 sí usas el método `close()` de los objetos que son análogos: *streams* para leer o escribir archivos. Acaso, por no cerrar el flujo de datos no puedas borrar el archivo.

Comment: efectivamente no me habia percatado que no habia cerrado con close() en la opcion 3 corregi ese problema y se soluciono, muchas gracias